# Appending a different number of elements to each group

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm pretty new to d3 And I'm trying to learn how it handles multi-dimensional arrays.

I need to append a different number of elements to a group based on the length of the nested array:

```
Var data = [
            [1,2,3],
            [1,2,3,4],
            [1,2,3,4,5]
           ];
```

Based on this example I would need to have 3 groups;
The first having 3 elements in it, the second having 4 and the third having 5.

What would be the correct way to iterate through the *Datum* assigned to each group?
Does d3 offer a method for doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple demo of looping through the groups first then looping through the elements in each group:

```
var data = [
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3,4],
    [1,2,3,4,5]
];

var viz = d3.select("#viz");
var groups = viz
                .selectAll("div.group")
                .data(data, function(d, index) { 
                   return d.key; 
                })
                .enter()
                .append("div")
                .classed('group', true)
                .text(function(d, i) { return 'group ' + i});

var nodes   = groups
                .selectAll("div.node")
                .data(function(d, index){ 
                   return d;
                })
                .enter().append("div")
                .classed('node', true)
                .text(function(d, i) { return d});
```

As a gist, with css styling for clarity
https://gist.github.com/widged/5203275

Let me know if this doesn't really answer your question

Comment: I found this tutorial really helpful to understand the basics of d3js http://code.hazzens.com/d3tut/lesson_1.html